# How to interpret Associativity/Precedence in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a question regarding associativity and precedence. Is this code

```hs
msum . map return
```

equivalent to this

```hs
(msum . map) return or
```

or this?

```hs
msum . (map return)
```

Generally how should one interpret such associativity and precedence in Haskell?

Comment: Think of juxtaposition as having precedence 10 (which is higher than the precedence that can be assigned to any operator using one of the fixity declarations like `infixr`). For comparison, composition is defined using `infixr 9 .`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary: `msum . map return == msum . (map return)` because juxtaposition has higher precedence than any explicit operator.

---

In general, both the associativity and the precedence of an operator is set using one of three *fixity* declarations.

```
infix
infixl
infixr
```

Each takes a precedence level between 0 and 9 and an operator. `infixl` creates a left-associative operator, `infixr` a right-associative operator, and `infix` a non-associative operator. (That means you can't chain such operators together without explicit parentheses; cf. `(==)`, as `3 == 5 == 9` is not allowed.)

For example, `4 * 3 * x ^ 2` parses as `(4 * 3) * (x ^ 2)` due to the following declarations:

```
infixl 7 *
infixr 8 ^
```

Multiplication is left associative, so `4 * 3` is evaluated first, before 12 is multiple by `x ^ 2`. It's not `(12 * x) ^2` because `^` has a higher precedence.

Function composition has the highest assignable precedence (the choice to use `infixr` over `infixl` is, I believe, arbitrary), being defined with

```
infixr 9 .
```

However, you can think of *juxtaposition* as a "null" operator for function application, with an even *higher* precedence of 10, higher than that allowed for *any* explicit operator. If it were syntactically allowed, you could imagine function application being defined with

```
infixl 10
```

Comment: you use the term juxtaposition as if it is a well known term...but unfortunately I am not familair with what juxtaposition means in this context :( mind explaining?

Comment: @FinlayWeber, that word just means putting two things side by side. For instance, in C++, function application does _not_ consist in the juxtaposition of function name and arguments, because you need to intersperse parenthesis and commas between them (e.g. `fun(a,b,c)`). In Haskell, on the contrary, function application is really the juxtaposition of the function name and all arguments (e.g. `fun a b c`).

Comment: Sorry about that, I had a definition of juxtaposition in an earlier draft, but apparently dropped it before clicking Post.

Answer (score 1):

The infix use of `.` has less precedence than function application, therefore when you write `msum . map return`, `map` "eats" `return`, and the result is composed with `msum` via infix `.`.

That's not the case if you apply `.` in function style: `(.) msum map return` is not valid because `(.)` "eats" `msum` ***and*** `map`, where the latter doesn't get a chance to be passed `return`. To fix this you would have to use parenthesis, like this: `(.) msum (map return)`.